# How to query a subset in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

The table I'm querying has two different kinds of contracts mixed up, 'a' and 'b%'. I need to query up the users who have both types of contracts expiring 60 days before `getdate()` and 20 days after `getdate()` (these numbers are put in declare clause). So far I've come up with this.

Now, I realize I'm doing something totally wrong. Basically, for any client having both types of contracts I need to get the above data of those, in a timeframe of `getdate() - mindate` and `getdate() + maxdate`.

To clear the confusion up around the types, here's the explanation. The table also has a `ProductType` column which features 'a' and 'b%' (to be used via like) and I need the client to have both types at the same time.

Any ideas?

```
DECLARE
    @mindate int = 60,
    @maxdate int = 20

SELECT TOP 10 
    pr.InsuredName, 
    pr.Document, 
    pr.BirthDate, 
    pr1.*
FROM
    PolicyRegistry pr
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
         SERIAL,
         NUMBER,
         EffectiveDate,
         ExpirationDate
     FROM
         PolicyRegistry) pr1 ON pr.InsuredName = pr1.InsuredName
ORDER BY
    pr.InsuredName
```

Comment: Are you *really* still using SQL Server 2005? That's been **completely** unsupported for 6-7 years now. It is *long* past time you sorted out your upgrade path.

Comment: Sorry, I totally misread the tags, my first question around here after so many years. Thanks for pointing it out, though!

Comment: What would really help here is table definitions and sample data as well as desired output for the sample data provided. That doesn't mean thousand of rows of sample but enough to cover the question at hand.

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected outcome, so it will be more clear for us what exact you are trying to achieve